What does ordinary differential equation mean, based on the word itself?
What does Ordinary Differential Equation mean? I know the mathematical definition, but I want to understand the meaning of the word "ordinary" here.
I know that an ordinary derivative is not a partial derivative, but what is the meaning ? What does "ordinary derivative" mean, based on the word itself?

I think it's just a modifier to distinguish from "partial derivative." When I say "derivative," I usually mean a function of a single variable if the context is clear.

The syntax (or perhaps one should rather say "syntactical role) of "ordinary" is rather boring: It's an adjective and fits into sentences and expressions the same way as other adjectives do. Do you mean to ask about the meaning of ordinary in this context, i.e. it's semantical content?

thank for your answer. So, can we say that an ordinary derivative is the derivative we are accustomed to with a single variable?

Yes i do. I mean the meaning of ordinary in this context.

See: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-ordinary-differential-equation (https://jeff560.tripod.com/o.html)

I don't fully understand what this question is asking. A term may be formally defined somewhere, or it may not be. A term may be frequently used to indicate a particular formal mathematical definition (or small range of definitions), or it may not. Are you asking about one of these two questions in the specific case of "ordinary derivative"? Are you asking about the history of the term "ordinary differential equation"? It's simply unclear to me.

Elaborating the "WHY" :
Etymology/History of the term can be traced back by the HSM Post which user Moo commented.
The semantic meaning can be considered like this :
We can have Linear Equation $ax+b=c$ where $x=(c-b)/x$
We can consider Quadratic Equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$
More generally , we can have Polynomial Equations $P(x)=0$ with Degree $n$
Next we have Trigonometric Equations like $\sin x + \cos x = 1$
We could have Exponential Equations like $e^x+x^2=8$
Each Case has a Description on what is involved & we want to get the unknown value $x$.
When we see Functional Equation , we might expect something like $f(x)+f(x+2)=2f(x)$ where we want to know what $f(x)$ is.
When the term Differential Equation was like-wise ostensibly used for Single Variable Single function Cases within Math Circles ages ago , the Authors writing about Equations involving Partial Differentials had a need to high-light that.
That gave rise to the term PDE "Partial" Differential Equation which requires us to find a function of 2 or more variables given some Data involving Partial Differentials.
Now the Issue got reversed : The Authors writing about Differential Equations not involving Partial Differentials had to "Disambiguate" !
Hence the term "Ordinary" entered the lingo to cover that !
Now-a-days , we can come across Systems of ODE , Systems of PDE , Linear ODE , Quasi-Linear PDE , Non-Linear PDE , Parabolic PDE , Degenerate PDE , . . .
Disambiguation is easy : Each term gives clues/hints on what in involved.
SHORT SUMMARY :
The time line is like : Derivatives -- Differential Equations -- Partial Differential Equations -- Ordinary Differential Equations
I have skipped Integration & Integral Equations here
Addendum : Suggested reading :
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_equation,_ordinary
The term "differential equations" was proposed in 1676 by G. Leibniz. The first studies of these equations were carried out in the late 17th century in the context of certain problems in mechanics and geometry.
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential_equation,_partial
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation
In mathematics, a partial differential equation (PDE) is an equation which computes a function between various partial derivatives of a multivariable function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation
Courtesy user Mauro ALLEGRANZA
https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-ordinary-differential-equation
Courtesy user Moo
